# Bootstrap Label with Arrow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-shapes

I'm figuring out how to make a Bootstrap Label point to a row. My solution is:

[image]

But is scales poorly and looks very unprofessional.

Based on Bootstrap Label, the code is:

```
.your-request-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: -67px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

.your-request-arrow:after {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left-color: #5bc0de;
    border-left-width: 14px;
    border-top-width: 7.9px;
    border-bottom-width: 7.8px;
    margin-top: -7.5px;
}
```

Comment: whats problem with that

Comment: The Arrow moves up and down on different zoom levels of the browser.

Comment: Why is the main element positioned absolutely?

Comment: Do you want like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7AKvM/199/?

Comment: @sanojlawrence The original code is from here: http://www.bootply.com/4eWhdvWE8B There you can also see how it is shifting.

Comment: @Paulie_D because I want to point it to the row without affecting the layout of the row. It should be outside, pointing in.

Comment: @JohannesWanzek: Would the text always be 'Your Request'?

Comment: @jbutler483 No of course not :D

Comment: @Etash This works perfectly! Post it into an answer and I will mark it as accepted!